# IntelliJ always runs entire ScalaTest suite 17 times

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, playframework-2.0, scalatest

I am using the following versions.

- IntelliJ 2020.2.3
- SBT 1.3.7
- Scala 2.11.12
- Play Framework SBT plugin 2.7.3

We have a project with an `app` directory with sources and a `test` directory with 44 tests in various packages.

When I run `sbt testOnly`, it runs all 44 unit tests. When I make an IntelliJ run configuration with ScalaTest and `Use sbt` checked, it also runs all 44 unit tests.

When I also check `Use UI with sbt` in the test configuration, the tests still run but it executes the entire test suite 17 times in a row, sequentially. The following line appears in the output, which is followed by an entire test run with results, and then it runs again and again until it stops after 17 times. The UI shows results for all 748 tests run.

```
[IJ][my-app] $ {file:/home/me/Documents/my-app/}root/ testOnly
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: In the run configurations, can you see a box saying "Repeat", with a 17? I haven't tried ScalaTest in IntelliJ before, but I think JUnit has something like that, and ScalaTest should too.

Comment: I don't see a box saying "Repeat", and I definitely have not configured anything to run 17 times.